# Decode _id field as UUID(binary format) to bson/interface{} from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I’m storing data with UUID as id format. It’s represented as binary in MongoDB.
My problem is, that while I decode a result from the DB, the id field is not decoding as UUID.
I’m not using structs here, if I use them, there is no problem, it decodes well.

In this scenario, I have generic repository(with interfaces, not with actual generics future)
So, we are decoding to bson objects

Go code

```
var response bson.M
    err := r.db.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": id}).Decode(&response)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &response, nil
```

output(HTTP json response)

```
{
    "_id": {
        "Subtype": 0,
        "Data": "d1rWV3UZSNu/s6ii14EFsA=="
    },
    "email": "user@user.com",
    "name": "john",
    "username": "doejohn"
}
```

expected output

```
{
    "_id": "513775c1-e34b-4ead-a886-03157f650336"
    "email": "user@email.com",
    "name": "john",
    "username": "johndoe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that we can marshal interfaces with `bson.Marshal(interface{})`

sample code;

```
userResponse,_ := getUser() // -> the return type is `interface{}`

var user models.User
bsonBytes, _ := bson.Marshal(userResponse)
bson.Unmarshal(bsonBytes, &user)
```

Now fields will be marshaled in the appropriate format with the model.
Sample model;

````
type User struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    Username  string    `json:"username" valid:"required"`
    Name      string    `json:"name" valid:"required"`
    Email     string    `json:"email" valid:"email"`
    Version   int       `json:"version" bson:"version,omitempty" default:"0"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}```
````